# Possessive form /restrictiveness

Tags: british-english, restrictive-clauses

If a specific name is connected to the possessive form is it restrictive and therefore leave out the comma? In the sense the information before the last noun at the end of the sentence modifies/acts as adjective, it in these contexts.

1. Star Wars will be remembered for the then groundbreaking special effects, and George Lucas' *villainous creation* *Darth Vader.*
2. The Harry Potter series is memorable for the chemistry between the three leads, and actor Ralph Fiennes' *evil character* *Lord Voldemort.*

Unlike: He liked Mary Shelley's most iconic creation, Frankenstein.
The good natured veneer of Dr Jekyll masked his evil character, Mr Hyde

If so what context would they appear non-restrictive form?

Comment: I don't see what difference a proper name makes. What commas are you leaving out?

Comment: Note the spelling of "villainous" (no "e")

Comment: The final comma as villain/creation look like they function as adjectives in these sorts of contexts, and therefore should not be set off with a comma